# How to map python dictionary key values to each other?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Suppose we have two dictionaries as below:

```
dict_a_to_b = {2:4, 6:9, 9:3}
dict_a_to_c = {2: 0.1, 6:0.2, 9: 0.8}
```

How to map these two dictionaries to make dict_c_to_b in python?

```
dict_c_to_b = {0.1:4, 0.2:9, 0.8:3}
```

Comment: What is the expected value of `dict_c_to_b`?

Comment: something like `0.1:4?` `0.8:3`?

Comment: `{dict_a_to_c[k]:dict_a_to_b[k] for k in dict_a_to_c}` ?

Comment: yes. We want dict_c_to_b i.e., {0.1:4, 0.2:9, 0.8:3}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `dict` comprehension - something like this:

```
dict_a_to_b = {2:4, 6:9, 9:3}
dict_a_to_c = {2: 0.1, 6:0.2, 9: 0.8}

result = {v: dict_a_to_b[k] for k, v in dict_a_to_c.items()}

print(result)  #-> {0.1: 4, 0.2: 9, 0.8: 3}
```

If you have extra keys in `dict_a_to_c` that don't show up in the other object, you can use an `if` condition to check if the key exists  first:

```
dict_a_to_b = {2:4, 6:9, 9:3}
dict_a_to_c = {2: 0.1, 6:0.2, 9: 0.8, 10:0.6, 50: 0.77, 12:0.56}

result = {v: dict_a_to_b[k] for k, v in dict_a_to_c.items()
          if k in dict_a_to_b}

print(result)  #-> {0.1: 4, 0.2: 9, 0.8: 3}
```

---

If you know the keys in both `dict_a_to_b` and `dict_a_to_c` appear in the same order, you can also use `zip` and just use the `values` on both `dict` objects:

```
result = dict(zip(dict_a_to_c.values(), dict_a_to_b.values()))

print(result)  #-> {0.1: 4, 0.2: 9, 0.8: 3}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the items in second dictionary is greater than items in first? Eg.

```dict_a_to_b = {2:4, 6:9, 9:3}

dict_a_to_c = {2: 0.1, 6:0.2, 9: 0.8, 10:0.6, 50: 0.77, 12:0.56}```

Output should be same i.e., : ```{0.1: 4, 0.2: 9, 0.8: 3}```

Comment: @mona I think the `zip` approach should work in that case - assuming that the keys appear in the same order as above.

Comment: another approach you can use is to add an `if` condition in the dict comprehension: `{v: dict_a_to_b[k] for k, v in dict_a_to_c.items() if k in dict_a_to_b}`