# How to map python dictionaries key values with unequal length of items?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Suppose we have two dictionaries as below:

```
dict_a_to_b = {2:4, 6:9, 9:3}

dict_a_to_c = {2: 0.1, 6:0.2, 9: 0.8, 10:0.6, 50: 0.77, 12:0.56}
```

How to map these two dictionaries to make dict_c_to_b in python? The items in second dictionary is greater than items in first.

Output should be:

```
dict_c_to_b = {0.1:4, 0.2:9, 0.8:3}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map python dictionary key values to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821768/how-to-map-python-dictionary-key-values-to-each-other)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{c: dict_a_to_b[a] for a, c in dict_a_to_c.items() if a in dict_a_to_b}
```

Do note that dictionary *values* don't have to be unique. If `dict_a_to_c` has duplicate values, the key associated with the last one wins here, assuming it is also available as a key in `dict_a_to_b`.

Comment: `{c: b for a, c in dict_a_to_c.items() if (b := dict_a_to_b.get(a))}` Using assignment expressions :)

Comment: @flakes That's bugged for falsey values.

Comment: Ah, thats true. I guess you need `if (b := dict_a_to_b.get(a)) is not None`. I liked how `b` is specifically listed in the `c: b`, but I guess its still not any more readable

Comment: An exact same question is posted in my comment above. Seems like a question from some sort of mooc.

Comment: @flakes The `c: dict_a_to_b[a]` is close, I think.

Comment: @SomeDude Not exact same, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821768/how-to-map-python-dictionary-key-values-to-each-other#comment128719143_72821818).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `for k in dict_a_to_b` and select corresponding values from both dictionaries.

```
dict_c_to_b = {dict_a_to_c[k]: dict_a_to_b[k] for k in dict_a_to_b}
{0.1: 4, 0.2: 9, 0.8: 3}
```

Comment: `for k in dict_a_to_b` iterates through the keys even without the `list` function.

Comment: Yes, `list` is not needed here. Thanks.

Comment: This is good, if it's known that `dict_a_to_b.keys() <= dict_a_to_c.keys()`. Not sure that can be assumed, though..